# Can Chrome's Incognito mode be disabled?

Tags: web-browser, corporate-policy, chrome

Is there a way to disable the use of anonymous navigation window (an Incognito window) in Google Chrome for a computer?

Comment: This question has been posed before - check here: http://superuser.com/questions/189327/how-can-i-disable-private-browsing-incognito-mode-in-browser-x and here: http://www.internetsafetyproject.org/wiki/how-disable-incognito-mode-chrome

Comment: As per Jeff's comment, this is covered elsewhere. It is not on topic here.

Answer (score 3):

*Anonymous navigation* is a confusing term. The navigation is not anonymous, it only leaves *less* traces on the computer.

Even if you disable that funcionality, the user could instruct the browser to wipe all data, and get the same. Or s/he could make the AppData folder for Chrome read-only, and get the same effect.

There's better ways to do that. The easier is to have a policy signed by the employees stating that all the internet access is logged, must only be used for business reason, and they agree with it. Install a company-wide proxy with logging enabled.

Comment: +1 there are always ways to get around supposed security. Disabling the incognito option is not a complete solution by any means.